# C# - Open a file with the associated program without invoking the command line

Tags: c#

Is it possible to open a file with the default program without invoking the command line?  I want to run a unit test and have the unit test open the file (PDF) at completion for visual inspection.

Comment: What does "without invoking the command line" mean?

Comment: I think he means not running via a command prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `Process.Start(filePath)`.
This will open the file in the user's default program.

Comment: wouldn't he have to import System.Diagnostics; if it didn't have the full namespace whilst invoking the command?

Comment: I have to call `Process.Start(pdfLocation).WaitForExit();`, which blocks the rest of my testing.  But, this will do.  If I have to test another PDF I will just wrap the command line and make synchronous calls that exit processes individually.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\file.pdf"); //i.e provide the full path!
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the following syntax:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\yourfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
 process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 process.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
 string arguments = fileArguments;
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = fileArguments;
 process.Start();
 process.WaitForExit();
```

This way you can invoke and put the file name in the pdf with parameters/arguments. You can also specify different programs and put it in the path, then the pdf name in the fileArguments. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "C:\...\...\myfile.pdf" );
```

the pdf should get opened by the default program associated to the .pdf extension.

is this what you wanted? I would be careful in putting this inside the unit test in case you include those tests in an automated build on the server, which runs with no logged in user, this could be an issue if it fails and if it does not fail, who is there to close Acrobat Reader? :D